# Generating all Euler Bricks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've recently been looking into Pythagorean Triples and [Euler Bricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick) and was wondering what the best way to generate all of them is.

I know from wider reading that there are 10 with c < 1000, and I have written a brute force code to find them, however it is incredibly slow. I can only find the Saunderson parameterisation, which doesn't generate all of them. So I'm not sure if there is a faster way. This is what I have so far as a code.

```
def isint(n):
     if n % 1 == 0:
         return True
     else:
         return False


def eulerbrick(n):
     euler_list = []
     for a in range(1,n):
         for b in range(a + 1,n):
             for c in range(b + 1,n):
                 ab = sqrt(a*a + b*b)
                 ac = sqrt(a*a + c*c)
                 bc = sqrt(b*b + c*c)

             if c > n:
                break

             if isint(ab) and isint(ac) and isint(bc):
                euler = [a,b,c]
                euler_list.append(euler)
return euler_list
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Maybe you can skip the innermost loop if `a`, `b` and `ab` doesn't form a Pythagorean triple. I mean, you can calculate `ab` before the `c`-loop  and if `ab` is not an integer, what's the point of running the whole `c`-loop at all?

Comment: @Aaron_ab: that's a Python idiom to check whether a float is a whole-number value (i.e. equal to an integer).

Comment: Can we have a little more detail on where you're missing something?  [Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) gets all the primitive triples with reasonable efficiency; where are your "holes"?

Answer (score 2):

I think, according to Wikipedia, if you want **all** Euler bricks, [you can not use any generating formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick#Generating_formula)

> Euler found at least two parametric solutions to the problem, but neither gives all solutions.

However, you already said, you've written a brute-force code to find them which is too slow. I think that stems from

```
ab = sqrt(a*a + b*b)
ac = sqrt(a*a + c*c)
bc = sqrt(b*b + c*c)
```

For every line, you calculate two square numbers and the square root - which doesn't sound like much, but in the end, that's going to sum up.

You can optimize your code if you calculate the square numbers immediately at the beginning of each loop section and store their value in a new variable. Furthermore, you should check as soon as possible if the numbers you already calculated pass the requirements for an Euler brick. Because if they don't, you don't have to calculate the other numbers and will save time there, too.

In the end, you have something like this:

```
import math
i = 1
j = 1000
for a in range(i, j):
    a_squared = a**2
    for b in range(a, j):
        b_squared = b**2
        d = math.sqrt(a_squared + b_squared)
        if not d.is_integer():
            continue
        for c in range(b, j):
            c_squared = c**2
            e = math.sqrt(a_squared + c_squared)
            if not e.is_integer():
                continue
            f = math.sqrt(b_squared + c_squared)
            if not f.is_integer():
                continue
            print("a={} b={} c={}".format(a, b, c))
```

Which doesn't take long at all and prints:

```
a=44 b=117 c=240
a=85 b=132 c=720
a=88 b=234 c=480
a=132 b=351 c=720
a=140 b=480 c=693
a=160 b=231 c=792
a=176 b=468 c=960
a=240 b=252 c=275
a=480 b=504 c=550
a=720 b=756 c=825
```